# Is there any formal proof for the correctness of long multiplication/division method?

Tags: number-theory

One could think of multiplication and division as repeated addition and subtraction respectively.
But when it comes to algorithms like long multiplication/division , how do we check their correctness ?

Are we assuming the correctness of such multiplication/division algorithm based on their correctness with smaller values ?

For eg: 12*10=120 , We could add 10, 12 times and verify it.

Consider numbers like this 489759 * 985681 = 482746140879 , Lets say someone came up with some other algorithm and produce some other result. How can one prove long multiplication method produced the correct result ,rather than adding 489759 , 985681 times.

Is there any formal way proof that assert the correctness ?

Comment: For multiplication, it's basically a glorified means of expansion in base ten (or whatever base you're working in).

For example: consider $1234 \times 6789$.

The algorithm of multiplication most students are introduced to reduces this to

$$1234 \times (6000 + 700 + 80 + 9) = 1234(6000) + 1234(700) + 1234(80) + 1234(9) = 1234(6)(10^3) + 1234(7)(10^2) + 1234(8)(10) + 1234(9)$$

Comment: The same calculations are done in the standard algorithm, even if it's a bit less apparent. In other, more formal words, the algorithm essentially makes use of the assumptions we're allowed to use because $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot)$ is a field, giving us the distribution of multiplication over addition. If some other algorithm achieved a different answer, then it's probably wrong, at least in the context of this number system.

It wouldn't be too difficult to try and generalize this if one wanted to verify validity, I imagine.

Comment: As for division ... I'm not really sure how to look at that algorithm so I'll have to leave that to someone else.

Comment: There is kind of intuitive-level "proof" for long division on MathIsFun: https://www.mathsisfun.com/long-division-organised.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our confidence in long multiplication comes from the fact that multiplication distributes with addition. In other words if $a = b + c$ then $ad = bd + cd$. The process of long multiplication works on this principal. I'll give an example of this to help show how it works.

Say we have $$\begin{equation}\begin{split}
11 \times 22 & = (10 + 1)(20 + 2) &\textrm{ Expand the numbers into addition } \\
& = 20(10 + 1) + 2(10 + 1) & \textrm{ Distribute the multiplication across the addition}  \\ & = (20 \times 10) + (20 \times 1) + (2 \times 10) + (2 \times 1) 
 & \textrm{ Distribute the multiplication across the inner addition } \\ 
& =  200 + 20 + 20 + 2 & \textrm{ Do the multiplications} \\ 
& = 242 & \textrm{ Do the additions} 
 \end{split}\end{equation}$$

The algorithm you learn for long multiplication is a convenient way to keep track of you doing this. It also takes the further step of expanding a number like $ 489759 = (4 \times 100000) + (8 \times 10000) + (9 \times 1000) \dots$ this way you can reduce the mulitiplication into multiplications between single digits and between powers of ten.